# Create Buttom for Parameter Calculation in Tableau

Tags: performance, filter, parameters, tableau-api

I maked a Interactiv Daschboard with 4 Parameters, where I can input a Start and End Date and 2 others where I can put in some values that should filter the Barcharts on the Dashboard. The Problem is whenever I change one of the Values in the Parameters, Tableau Starts Calculating. That makes me crazy cause when I want to change all 4 Parameters I need to wait 4 Calculations to finish!!!

Is there a possibility that I set up something like a Button so I first can change the Paramater Values and than after clicking on the Button Tableau should Start calculating with the new Values of the Parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pause the automatic updates on Desktop. Then set your filters/parameters, and resume.

[image]

The same for Server.

[image]

See the docs for more information. http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/queries_autoupdates.html

Comment: Hi Bernardo, Do we have ability to use API's and connect to tableau server to control auto updates ?

Comment: @maverick I'm not sure. Tableau does have a JavaScript API but I've never used it and I'm not familiar with JavaScript.